# Minwax “One Coat Polyurethane” — does it work?

Tags: finishing, polyurethane

I stumbled across Minwax's [One Coat Polyurethane](http://www.minwax.com/wood-products/clear-protective-finishes/interior/minwax-one-coat-polyurethane) on their website. It purports to built a finish equal to 3 coats of regular poly in a single application. I'm curious if anybody has used it and has any input/thoughts/feedback on how it works and whether it's worth trying out.

Comment: I've used it. I've used the black gloss. It's not the greatest looking finish but it is easy to apply and so far it hasn't caused me any issues. I use it for quick stuff that I want to look decent but not spend much time on, I don't particularly like the texture of it (it invokes... a candied apple, I guess) but that's just personal preference. I don't really have much more interesting info about it though but I'm sure somebody will post a good answer.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for your input! So the finish isn't quite the same as with other polyurethane products in your experience?

Comment: It feels like a really, really thick coat of poly over a stain. I thought it looked... cheap. Like a counter in a corner store or something.  But try it. See if you like it. See if you can find a half pint. It's very easy to work with. Also bear in mind that I am just a light hobbyist with relatively little experience.

Comment: I've never used it but all I can think when I read it has a finish "equal to 3 coats of regular poly in a single application" is that if that was really true and it was equal in all ways, then nobody would use regular poly.

Comment: @WhatEvil I suspect that it's not as cost effective, and the claim of “3 coats” is probably exaggerated, but I'd like to hear from people who've used it rather than write it off out of skepticism.

Comment: @WhatEvil Well one specific reason that it could never dominate the market regardless of its quality is that it does not come in every color of stain and every variation of other finishes and glossiness available that you might want to put some kind of oil or water based poly on top of. It is a convenience product not so much a replacement for all things.

Comment: Your question as written seems too vague and open-ended. It would be helpful if you shared what, specifically, caught your interest in this finish and if you explicitly asked for specific concrete comparisons. Are you interested in comparisons of the application process? Durability? Are there other specific products or types of products with which you would like to see comparisons? It would also be helpful if you included the types of projects on which you intend to use it and/or what properties are most important to you in a finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used it on a coffee table I built. The top consisted of 1x2s of different species with different stains. Used the One Coat on it. It went on smooth and same appearance across all the boards. It had a decent amount of working time where it didn't dry out by the time I got to the other side. I used the clear satin. Pretty matte, tiny bit of sheen but better than most. Virtually no brush strokes. Only thing is on some boards the grain was raised and the One Coat covered it, but went into the valleys a bit. Meaning it was not 100% smooth in that portion but couldn't tell until you were right against it. Still had full coverage and protected though. Took a screw driver to scrape a test piece. Held up as well as others. I plan on using it going forward on the pieces in my house.